# Detecting/Capturing UAC prompt in Windows

Tags: python, pyautogui, uac

I'm making a program which runs on an infinite loop and reports when UAC is launched or when the certain condition is met. I'm trying to detect whenever UAC prompt is triggered by capturing window title of running applications.

I've also used `pyautogui` to capture screenshot of the UAC prompt window and then locate it using `locateOnScreen()` method but when UAC is lauched pyautogui returns exactly the same exception that is mentioned below. `pywintypes.error: (1400, 'GetClassName', 'Invalid window handle.')`

##### Example:

```py
... 
While True: 
    hWnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() 
    tWnd = win32gui.GetWindowText(hWnd) 
    print(tWnd) 
    time.sleep(1) 
...

# Captured screenshot of UAC prompt using keyboard shortcuts and then
# tried to detect it using pyautogui but it also returns None.

img = Image.open(PATH_TO_IMAGE) # using PIL lib
lWnd = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img)
print(lWnd)
```

This grabs the title text of every window but as soon as UAC prompt is launched, it throws an exception `pywintypes.error: (1400, 'GetClassName', 'Invalid window handle.')` Whereas it should print the title of UAC Prompt which is "**User Account Control**".

What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Is the UAC on "Secure Desktop" (transparent gray background)? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/how-does-the-windows-secure-desktop-mode-work

Comment: @criztovyl Yes it is, but even if I lower down the uac settings (not turn off) it still won't get the title

Comment: Isn’t the whole point of the way UAC is architected to prevent exactly what you’re trying to do? Wouldn’t it be concerning if UAC prompts could be dismissed by anyone but the user…? Can you give a bit more context about why you’re trying to bypass UAC to begin with?

Comment: @esqew I'm not trying to "bypass" the UAC, I just want to know programmatically that it is being displayed on the screen.

Comment: "I just want to know programmatically that it is being displayed on the screen." Why?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an allowance for *screen readers* to read the UAC screen.

- manifest your application as `uiAccess="true"`
- run it from a *"protected"* location (i.e. `C:\Program Files`)

Then your application will be allowed to **see** the UAC dialog.